# Pgpool-II connection pooling with Load balancing disabled still make request to stand by DB node. Causing client to disconnect

Tags: load-balancing, postgresql, tcp, pgpool

I have a problem with pgpool-II load balancer. Currently I have turned off pgpool-II load balancer but somehow it still made request to my standby node. How can this happen? This make my child go disconnected.
[This is the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwjC6.png)

[This is the configuration file for load balancer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sP8Y2.png)

[And this is the backend settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPDwF.png)

Can you guys show me how to make this right? Thank you in advance.